# Creating a subreddit filter list

Tags: python-3.x, praw

Im using Python 3.6 and PRAW 6, trying to do a simple bot with subreddit filters that cross posts hot submissions into another subreddit . However, I cant seem to set up my subreddit filter properly when initiating the script.

This is pretty annoying because it has worked before. I read that 403 HTTP response was authentication issues but that doesnt make sense. I can individually add subreddits into the filter and I even managed to iteratively remove subreddits from the saved subreddit filter list which I had set up beforehand.

I have a `sub_filter.txt` file with the list of subreddits I would like to filter out containing strings like so:

`tifu
jokes
worldnews`

Then,

```
with open("sub_filter.txt") as q:
subreddit_filter = subreddit_filter.split("\n")
subreddit_filter = list(filter(None, subreddit_filter))
subreddit_filter = list(subreddit_filter)

for i in subreddit_filter:
    filter_list = reddit.subreddit('all').filters.add(i)

for subreddit in reddit.subreddit('all').filters:
    print(subreddit)
```

This is the error message I get when it reaches the code to iteratively add subreddits into the subreddit filter

```
for i in subreddit_filter:
    filter_list = reddit.subreddit('all').filters.add(i)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Qixuan\Desktop\Programming programmes\Reddit\weweet-bot\weweet-code.py", line 23, in <module>
    reddit.subreddit('all').filters.add(i)
  File "C:\Users\Qixuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\subreddit.py", line 974, in add
    "PUT", url, data={"model": dumps({"name": str(subreddit)})}
  File "C:\Users\Qixuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 577, in request
    method, path, data=data, files=files, params=params
  File "C:\Users\Qixuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "C:\Users\Qixuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 130, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.Forbidden: received 403 HTTP response
```

Any help is greatly appreaciated! Im also not very proficient at coding so please be forgiving!

Comment: Can you fix the code sample? Your `with` block should be followed by at least one indented line. In addition, the variable `q` is defined and never used, and the variable `subreddit_filter` is used before it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

> I read that 403 HTTP response was authentication issues

403 does indeed indicate an authentication issue. Try adding the following line immediately after `reddit` is defined:

```
print(reddit.user.me())
```

If you are properly authenticated, this will print your username. Otherwise, you need to fix your credentials (username, password, client ID, client secret, user agent).